# The default display currency you selected is not available in allowed currencies

Tags: magento2, currency

I am new in magento 2, I want to set my currency to dinar but I did not find this currency. How to add a new currency BO. 
Other question: The Us dollar  is not available in allowed currencies even it appear in the list of allowed currencies please tell me what to do to resolve these two problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: in currency options there are couple of 'Dinar' which one you want to pick?
under stores->configuration->general->currency setup

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that from **Allowed Currencies List** > The same currency is selected. Else you will end up with the "the default display currency you selected is not available in allowed currencies" error. 
.
[image: Currencies Selection in magento]

Comment: can you please help me in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274483/filter-collection-of-options-of-custom-attribute-magento-2